# Okta authentication using Power Pages / Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

I am new to Power platform and I am exploring various options we may have for authentication/authorization.

We use Okta for auth.  Just wondering if Power Apps supports external SSO/IDP (specifically Okta).  Heard that Power Pages supports any SSO/IDP (including Okta).  However, I am unsure if I can leverage both Power Apps and Power Pages for our web application and just use Power Pages for auth (still sharing the same session context with Power Apps).

Any advice?